# How Precedence and Associativity work in java?

Tags: java, increment, operator-precedence

I have been working with addition , post increment and assignment Operator.I think post increment (b++) have higest precedence so it is evalute first.Then the value of b became 11 (b =11).After addition is perform

```
b+10+c+d
```

=11+10+20+30

=71

.71 is assigned to variable  a. But when i print the value of a it display 70 instead of 71.

```
public class Operator {
        
public static void main(String[] args) {
                int a;
                int b,c,d;
                b = 10;
                c = 20;
                d = 30;
                a = b +b++ + c+ d;
                System.out.println(a);
        
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: `b++` will return the value of b prior to the increment =10, while `++b` will return the value of b after the increment i.e. 11

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, break it down according to the rules. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/server.761/es_eql/src/ceql_expr_precedence_rules.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

Since in your example, b++ is a postfix, it means "increment the value of b by one but return the old value".

Therefore

```
            int a;
            int b,c,d;
            b = 10;
            c = 20;
            d = 30;
            a = b + b++ + c+ d;
            System.out.println(a);
```

Becomes

```
//         b=11
a = (10) + (10) + 20 + 30
  = 70
```